# Map route in MVC to match a dot in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way to define route like this

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Language",
                url: "{controller}/{action}.{culture}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And be able to handle url like http://www.domain.com/Test/Create.us-US?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but add route for url like http://www.domain.com/Test/Create without dot at the end

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Language",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "us-US" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can create route without with dot but you use the special caracter to the root. When we declare the method at the controler at that time you can specify the Action name define in the route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DashboardV1_bm", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

[HttpPost, ActionName("DashboardV1_bm")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DashboardV1(int id)
        {
            Shift shift = db.Shifts.Find(id);
            db.Shifts.Remove(shift);
            db.SaveChanges();

            this.AddToastMessage("Delete", "Record is successfully deleted !", ToastType.Success);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

For more information, please visit my blog:
http://programmingcode.in/create-routemap-to-access-new-created-view-page-in-mvc-dot-net/